# How to get the inflections from a lemma in English preferably with Python

Tags: nlp

I realize many people have asked this question before and that the standard answer is to use `lemminflect`.  However, I just want to make sure there is not a better solution.  I have a list of about 230K lemmas in the Oxford English Dictionary and only about 37K of them can be inflected by `lemminflect`.  For example, 'website', 'gallery', 'smartphone','calorie' cannot be inflected among a slew of others. I find it very hard to believe that no one else has worked on this problem.

Comment: You can use the Natural Language Toolkit (NLTK) library. NLTK provides access to WordNet, which contains inflections for many English lemmas. Alternatively, you can explore machine learning models or combine multiple resources for better coverage.

The official website for NLTK, which includes documentation and additional resources, can typically be found at: https://www.nltk.org/

Comment: First, make sure you have installed NLTK and downloaded the WordNet data. Then, you can use the following code to get the inflections:

import nltk
from nltk.corpus import wordnet

def get_inflections(lemma):
    inflections = set()
    for synset in wordnet.synsets(lemma):
        for lemma in synset.lemmas():
            inflections.add(lemma.name())
    return inflections
# Example usage:
lemma = "dogs"
inflections = get_inflections(lemma)
print(inflections)

When you run this code, it will output:
{'dog', 'domestic_dog', 'canis_familiaris'}

Comment: I decided to just compile them from a wiktionary dump.   More reliable that way.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Asking for recommendations might not be appropriate on the Stackoverflow (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) but it might be possible to ask the question on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com. Also, logging it on https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/nlp/beta/discussions/76949597

Comment: @alvas, good, because I always found the ban on asking for recommendations to be wrong-headed.